# How to prevent Nodejs process from accessing certain areas

Tags: javascript, node.js, security

I've build a nodejs hosting service but the problem is security, How can I prevent developers from crawling other developers files and codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to run everything is separate containers.

Another option would be to use jails, zones and other techniques. It depends on what OS you're using.

At the very least you should make sure that everyone has a separate part of the filesystem with 600 permissions but you also need to protects ports and other resources, so zones and containers or some kind of virtualization are the way to go.